# Handling keyboard events, playername shows up for a second and dissappears?

Tags: c#, opentk

i'be been making  a pingpong game in my spare time and ran into a problem. What i ideally like is when the gameover screen shows. That the player can enter their names dynamically. for example it should be Name: H  then another character pressed Name: Hu

I ovverode the keydown event, the playernme is just a list variable to store characters retrieved from key presses

```
public void Keydown(object sender, KeyboardKeyEventArgs e)
        {

            ///store handles the temp output of the ToCharArray
            char[] store = e.Key.ToString().ToCharArray();
            playernme.Add(store[0]);

        }
```

This playernme is then passed on to the renderer where the GUI label is

```
 foreach (char c in playernme)
            {
                playernamed += c.ToString();
            }
            GUI.Label(new Rectangle(0, (int)(fontSize / 2f), (int)width, (int)(fontSize * 4  )), "Name: " + playernamed , (int)fontSize, StringAlignment.Center);
```

This is what happens in the gameover screen

[image]

it seems like its a simple problem which i cannot wrap my head around. I know that the keydown causes multiple characters to appear but i couldn't find any correlation with that and why the name doesn't show